# Golang import struct and share over all app

Tags: go

I would like to import package and create new struct in main() func.

```
// main.go
import "testapp/app"
a := app.GetApp()
db, err := a.ConnectDatabase()
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

// testapp/app.go
func (a *App) ConnectDatabase() {
  db, err := sql.Open()
  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
  }
  a.db = db
}
```

I've got error:

> app.ConnectDatabase() used as value

How can I fix that?

Comment: `App.ConnectDatabase` does not return any values.

Comment: It works, but how to assign to struct pointer my db connection? func ConnectDatabase() (*sql.DB, error) {
 db, err := sql.Open()
 if err != nil {
  return nil, err
 }

 return db, nil
}

Comment: Your purported error doesn't match your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

you might want to solve this like:

```
// main.go
import "testapp/app"
func main(){
    a := app.GetApp()
    err := a.ConnectDatabase()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    a.db. //interesting db code here
}

// testapp/app.go
func (a *App) ConnectDatabase() error{
  db, err := sql.Open()
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  a.db = db
  return nil
}
```